# How to parse Steam's JSON response using VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, steam

**EDIT:**

Well to explain what I finally need:

We are looking for what steam tells us about an specific app, like "Dead by Daylight".

```
Dim address As String = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=381210&filters=basic"

Dim link As WebClient = New WebClient()

Dim info As String = link.DownloadString(address)
```

As result there is the following JSON-like server answer.

```
{"381210":{"success":true,"data":{"type":"game","name":"Dead by Daylight","steam_appid":381210,"required_age":0,"is_free":false,"dlc":[492140,509060,530710,530711,554380],"detailed_description":"<h1>Digitale Deluxe-Edition<\/h1><p><img src=\"http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/381210\/extras\/dlx_1.jpg?t=1480018883\">\r<br>The Deluxe Edition includes the base game, official soundtrack, digital art book, two masks for PAYDAY 2.<\/p><br><h1>\u00dcber das Spiel<\/h1><strong>Der Tod ist keine Zuflucht.<\/strong>\r<br>\r<br>Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft, Folter und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen. \r<br>\r<br>Die \u00dcberlebenden spielen in der Dritte-Person-Perspektive und haben den Vorteil, einen besseren \u00dcberblick \u00fcber die Situation zu haben. Der Killer spielt in der Ich-Perspektive und ist mehr auf seine Beute fokusiert.\r<br>\r<br>Das Ziel der \u00dcberlebenden bei jedem Zusammentreffen ist es, dem T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen, ohne vom Killer gefangen zu werden \u2013 etwas, das sich leichter anh\u00f6rt, als es ist, vor allem, wenn sich die Umgebung jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndert.\r<br>\r<br>Mehr Informationen \u00fcber das Spiel sind unter <a href=\"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\"  >http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com<\/a> verf\u00fcgbar.<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Hauptmerkmale<\/h2>\r\u2022\t<strong>\u00dcberlebt gemeinsam... Oder auch nicht<\/strong> - \u00dcberlebende k\u00f6nnen entweder mit den anderen kooperieren oder eigenn\u00fctzig sein. Deine \u00dcberlebenschance wird variieren, je nachdem, ob ihr als Team zusammenarbeitet oder du allein loslegst. Wird es dir gelingen, den Killer zu \u00fcberlisten und seinen T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen ?\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Wo bin ich? <\/strong> - Jedes Level ist verfahrensorientiert angelegt, daher wei\u00dft du nie, was dich erwartet. Zuf\u00e4llige Spawnpunkte bedeuten, dass du dich niemals sicher f\u00fchlen wirst, da sich die Welt und ihre Gefahren jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndern.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Ein Festmahl f\u00fcr Killer <\/strong> - Dead by Daylight sch\u00f6pft aus allen Ecken der Horrowelt. Als Killer kannst du alles spielen, vom m\u00e4chtigen Zers\u00e4bler bis zum furchteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden, paranormalen Entitus.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Tiefer und tiefer <\/strong> - Jeder Killer und \u00dcberlebender hat sein eigenes, tiefes Fortschrittssystem und jede Menge Freischaltbares, das auf deine pers\u00f6nliche Strategie angepasst werden kann. Erfahrung, F\u00e4higkeiten und Verst\u00e4ndnis der Umgebung sind der Schl\u00fcssel zum Jagen oder \u00dcberlisten des Killers.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Reale Spieler, reale Angst <\/strong> - Die verfahrensabh\u00e4ngigen Levels und wirkliche, menschliche Reaktionen bis hin zum Horror, machen jeden Spielabschnitt zu einem unerwarteten Szenario. Du kannst nie vorher sagen, wie es ausgehen wird. Ambiente, Musik und entspannte Umgebungen vereinen sich zu einer angsteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden Erfahrung. Vielleicht k\u00f6nntest du mit gen\u00fcgend Zeit sogar herausfinden, was sich im Nebel verbirgt.","about_the_game":"<strong>Der Tod ist keine Zuflucht.<\/strong>\r<br>\r<br>Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft, Folter und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen. \r<br>\r<br>Die \u00dcberlebenden spielen in der Dritte-Person-Perspektive und haben den Vorteil, einen besseren \u00dcberblick \u00fcber die Situation zu haben. Der Killer spielt in der Ich-Perspektive und ist mehr auf seine Beute fokusiert.\r<br>\r<br>Das Ziel der \u00dcberlebenden bei jedem Zusammentreffen ist es, dem T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen, ohne vom Killer gefangen zu werden \u2013 etwas, das sich leichter anh\u00f6rt, als es ist, vor allem, wenn sich die Umgebung jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndert.\r<br>\r<br>Mehr Informationen \u00fcber das Spiel sind unter <a href=\"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\"  >http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com<\/a> verf\u00fcgbar.<h2 class=\"bb_tag\">Hauptmerkmale<\/h2>\r\u2022\t<strong>\u00dcberlebt gemeinsam... Oder auch nicht<\/strong> - \u00dcberlebende k\u00f6nnen entweder mit den anderen kooperieren oder eigenn\u00fctzig sein. Deine \u00dcberlebenschance wird variieren, je nachdem, ob ihr als Team zusammenarbeitet oder du allein loslegst. Wird es dir gelingen, den Killer zu \u00fcberlisten und seinen T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen ?\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Wo bin ich? <\/strong> - Jedes Level ist verfahrensorientiert angelegt, daher wei\u00dft du nie, was dich erwartet. Zuf\u00e4llige Spawnpunkte bedeuten, dass du dich niemals sicher f\u00fchlen wirst, da sich die Welt und ihre Gefahren jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndern.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Ein Festmahl f\u00fcr Killer <\/strong> - Dead by Daylight sch\u00f6pft aus allen Ecken der Horrowelt. Als Killer kannst du alles spielen, vom m\u00e4chtigen Zers\u00e4bler bis zum furchteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden, paranormalen Entitus.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Tiefer und tiefer <\/strong> - Jeder Killer und \u00dcberlebender hat sein eigenes, tiefes Fortschrittssystem und jede Menge Freischaltbares, das auf deine pers\u00f6nliche Strategie angepasst werden kann. Erfahrung, F\u00e4higkeiten und Verst\u00e4ndnis der Umgebung sind der Schl\u00fcssel zum Jagen oder \u00dcberlisten des Killers.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Reale Spieler, reale Angst <\/strong> - Die verfahrensabh\u00e4ngigen Levels und wirkliche, menschliche Reaktionen bis hin zum Horror, machen jeden Spielabschnitt zu einem unerwarteten Szenario. Du kannst nie vorher sagen, wie es ausgehen wird. Ambiente, Musik und entspannte Umgebungen vereinen sich zu einer angsteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden Erfahrung. Vielleicht k\u00f6nntest du mit gen\u00fcgend Zeit sogar herausfinden, was sich im Nebel verbirgt.","short_description":"Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen.","supported_languages":"Englisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Franz\u00f6sisch, Italienisch, Deutsch, Spanisch, Russisch, Chinesisch (vereinfacht)<br><strong>*<\/strong>Sprachen mit voller Audiounterst\u00fctzung","header_image":"http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/381210\/header.jpg?t=1480018883","website":"http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com","pc_requirements":{"minimum":"<strong>Minimum:<\/strong>\r<br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> 64-bit Betriebssystem (Windows 7, Windows 8 &amp; Windows 8.1)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> Intel Core i3-4170 or AMD FX-8120\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Arbeitsspeicher:<\/strong> 8 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> DX11 Kompatible GeForce GTX 460 1GB oder AMD HD 6850 1GB  o\tDirectX: Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Netzwerk:<\/strong> Breitband-Internetverbindung\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicherplatz:<\/strong> 15 GB verf\u00fcgbarer Speicherplatz\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Soundkarte:<\/strong> DX11 kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>","recommended":"<strong>Empfohlen:<\/strong>\r<br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> 64-bit Betriebssystem (Windows 7, Windows 8 &amp; Windows 8.1)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> Intel Core i3-4170 or AMD FX-8300 oder h\u00f6her\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Arbeitsspeicher:<\/strong> 8 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> DX11 Kompatible GeForce 760 or AMD HD 8800 oder h\u00f6her mit 4GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Netzwerk:<\/strong> Breitband-Internetverbindung\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicherplatz:<\/strong> 15 GB verf\u00fcgbarer Speicherplatz\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Soundkarte:<\/strong> DX11 kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>"},"mac_requirements":[],"linux_requirements":[],"legal_notice":"Dead by Daylight ist eine Handelsmarke von Behaviour Interactive Inc. Alle anderen Handelsmarken sind Eigentum ihrer jeweiligen Inhaber. Entwickelt von Behaviour Digital und publiziert von Starbreeze Studios. Alle Rechte vorbehalten."}}}
```

Finally I'd like to deserialize this so each property can be accessed as a string

Like

```
Dim apptype as String = "game"
Dim appname as String = "Dead by Daylight"
```

Comment: a) Please stop putting tags in your titles b) the json on your deleted post had more data, are you sure this is it? c) you ought not delete posts that are downvoted - it will still lead to a throttle and/or ban d) you cant deserialize to `Object` you need a class or if you only want some thing, you can parse it.  Study the links under **Related**

Comment: ...also the NET JavaScriptSerializer is not meant for desktop apps, Microsoft recommends JSON.NET for serialization and deserialization.  These are the first words on the MSDN JavaScriptSerializer page.

Comment: Can the game be static. The answer will vary significantly depending on if you already know the 381210 number, or if you need to find that dynamically

Comment: I know the answer depends on the appid we choose. This is just an example. It will be not the problem to make it generally.

Answer (score 0):

To help visualize the class structure you need to build you can [use](http://jsonutils.com/) this tool

I will assume you need to have this be dynamic (forgive my hack as I am not familar with VB and JSON) so I replace the *381210* property with a static *id* property name so our class/s can reflect the data more easily.

First I we get the data (JSON) parse it (yes parse) then we deserialize it into our class properties so we can access the data easily later on.

Put this section in your event (such as a button click)

```
   'This is your JSON string from STEAM
    Dim a As String = "{""381210"":{""success"":true,""data"":{""type"":""game"",""name"":""Dead by Daylight"",""steam_appid"":381210,""required_age"":0,""is_free"":false,""dlc"":[492140,509060,530710,530711,554380],""detailed_description"":""<h1>Digitale Deluxe-Edition<\/h1><p><img src=\""http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/381210\/extras\/dlx_1.jpg?t=1480018883\"">\r<br>The Deluxe Edition includes the base game, official soundtrack, digital art book, two masks for PAYDAY 2.<\/p><br><h1>\u00dcber das Spiel<\/h1><strong>Der Tod ist keine Zuflucht.<\/strong>\r<br>\r<br>Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft, Folter und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen. \r<br>\r<br>Die \u00dcberlebenden spielen in der Dritte-Person-Perspektive und haben den Vorteil, einen besseren \u00dcberblick \u00fcber die Situation zu haben. Der Killer spielt in der Ich-Perspektive und ist mehr auf seine Beute fokusiert.\r<br>\r<br>Das Ziel der \u00dcberlebenden bei jedem Zusammentreffen ist es, dem T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen, ohne vom Killer gefangen zu werden \u2013 etwas, das sich leichter anh\u00f6rt, als es ist, vor allem, wenn sich die Umgebung jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndert.\r<br>\r<br>Mehr Informationen \u00fcber das Spiel sind unter <a href=\""https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com\"" target=\""_blank\"" rel=\""noreferrer\""  >http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com<\/a> verf\u00fcgbar.<h2 class=\""bb_tag\"">Hauptmerkmale<\/h2>\r\u2022\t<strong>\u00dcberlebt gemeinsam... Oder auch nicht<\/strong> - \u00dcberlebende k\u00f6nnen entweder mit den anderen kooperieren oder eigenn\u00fctzig sein. Deine \u00dcberlebenschance wird variieren, je nachdem, ob ihr als Team zusammenarbeitet oder du allein loslegst. Wird es dir gelingen, den Killer zu \u00fcberlisten und seinen T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen ?\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Wo bin ich? <\/strong> - Jedes Level ist verfahrensorientiert angelegt, daher wei\u00dft du nie, was dich erwartet. Zuf\u00e4llige Spawnpunkte bedeuten, dass du dich niemals sicher f\u00fchlen wirst, da sich die Welt und ihre Gefahren jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndern.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Ein Festmahl f\u00fcr Killer <\/strong> - Dead by Daylight sch\u00f6pft aus allen Ecken der Horrowelt. Als Killer kannst du alles spielen, vom m\u00e4chtigen Zers\u00e4bler bis zum furchteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden, paranormalen Entitus.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Tiefer und tiefer <\/strong> - Jeder Killer und \u00dcberlebender hat sein eigenes, tiefes Fortschrittssystem und jede Menge Freischaltbares, das auf deine pers\u00f6nliche Strategie angepasst werden kann. Erfahrung, F\u00e4higkeiten und Verst\u00e4ndnis der Umgebung sind der Schl\u00fcssel zum Jagen oder \u00dcberlisten des Killers.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Reale Spieler, reale Angst <\/strong> - Die verfahrensabh\u00e4ngigen Levels und wirkliche, menschliche Reaktionen bis hin zum Horror, machen jeden Spielabschnitt zu einem unerwarteten Szenario. Du kannst nie vorher sagen, wie es ausgehen wird. Ambiente, Musik und entspannte Umgebungen vereinen sich zu einer angsteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden Erfahrung. Vielleicht k\u00f6nntest du mit gen\u00fcgend Zeit sogar herausfinden, was sich im Nebel verbirgt."",""about_the_game"":""<strong>Der Tod ist keine Zuflucht.<\/strong>\r<br>\r<br>Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft, Folter und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen. \r<br>\r<br>Die \u00dcberlebenden spielen in der Dritte-Person-Perspektive und haben den Vorteil, einen besseren \u00dcberblick \u00fcber die Situation zu haben. Der Killer spielt in der Ich-Perspektive und ist mehr auf seine Beute fokusiert.\r<br>\r<br>Das Ziel der \u00dcberlebenden bei jedem Zusammentreffen ist es, dem T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen, ohne vom Killer gefangen zu werden \u2013 etwas, das sich leichter anh\u00f6rt, als es ist, vor allem, wenn sich die Umgebung jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndert.\r<br>\r<br>Mehr Informationen \u00fcber das Spiel sind unter <a href=\""https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/linkfilter\/?url=http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com\"" target=\""_blank\"" rel=\""noreferrer\""  >http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com<\/a> verf\u00fcgbar.<h2 class=\""bb_tag\"">Hauptmerkmale<\/h2>\r\u2022\t<strong>\u00dcberlebt gemeinsam... Oder auch nicht<\/strong> - \u00dcberlebende k\u00f6nnen entweder mit den anderen kooperieren oder eigenn\u00fctzig sein. Deine \u00dcberlebenschance wird variieren, je nachdem, ob ihr als Team zusammenarbeitet oder du allein loslegst. Wird es dir gelingen, den Killer zu \u00fcberlisten und seinen T\u00f6tungsgebiet zu entkommen ?\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Wo bin ich? <\/strong> - Jedes Level ist verfahrensorientiert angelegt, daher wei\u00dft du nie, was dich erwartet. Zuf\u00e4llige Spawnpunkte bedeuten, dass du dich niemals sicher f\u00fchlen wirst, da sich die Welt und ihre Gefahren jedes Mal, wenn du spielst, ver\u00e4ndern.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Ein Festmahl f\u00fcr Killer <\/strong> - Dead by Daylight sch\u00f6pft aus allen Ecken der Horrowelt. Als Killer kannst du alles spielen, vom m\u00e4chtigen Zers\u00e4bler bis zum furchteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden, paranormalen Entitus.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Tiefer und tiefer <\/strong> - Jeder Killer und \u00dcberlebender hat sein eigenes, tiefes Fortschrittssystem und jede Menge Freischaltbares, das auf deine pers\u00f6nliche Strategie angepasst werden kann. Erfahrung, F\u00e4higkeiten und Verst\u00e4ndnis der Umgebung sind der Schl\u00fcssel zum Jagen oder \u00dcberlisten des Killers.\r<br>\r<br>\u2022\t<strong>Reale Spieler, reale Angst <\/strong> - Die verfahrensabh\u00e4ngigen Levels und wirkliche, menschliche Reaktionen bis hin zum Horror, machen jeden Spielabschnitt zu einem unerwarteten Szenario. Du kannst nie vorher sagen, wie es ausgehen wird. Ambiente, Musik und entspannte Umgebungen vereinen sich zu einer angsteinfl\u00f6\u00dfenden Erfahrung. Vielleicht k\u00f6nntest du mit gen\u00fcgend Zeit sogar herausfinden, was sich im Nebel verbirgt."",""short_description"":""Dead by Daylight ist ein Multiplayer-Horrorspiel (4vs1), in dem ein Spieler die Rolle eines wilden Killers \u00fcbernimmt und die anderen vier Spieler als \u00dcberlebende spielen, die versuchen, dem Killer zu entkommen sowie Gefangenschaft und T\u00f6tung zu entgehen."",""supported_languages"":""Englisch<strong>*<\/strong>, Franz\u00f6sisch, Italienisch, Deutsch, Spanisch, Russisch, Chinesisch (vereinfacht)<br><strong>*<\/strong>Sprachen mit voller Audiounterst\u00fctzung"",""header_image"":""http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/381210\/header.jpg?t=1480018883"",""website"":""http:\/\/www.deadbydaylight.com"",""pc_requirements"":{""minimum"":""<strong>Minimum:<\/strong>\r<br><ul class=\""bb_ul\""><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> 64-bit Betriebssystem (Windows 7, Windows 8 &amp; Windows 8.1)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> Intel Core i3-4170 or AMD FX-8120\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Arbeitsspeicher:<\/strong> 8 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> DX11 Kompatible GeForce GTX 460 1GB oder AMD HD 6850 1GB  o\tDirectX: Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Netzwerk:<\/strong> Breitband-Internetverbindung\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicherplatz:<\/strong> 15 GB verf\u00fcgbarer Speicherplatz\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Soundkarte:<\/strong> DX11 kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>"",""recommended"":""<strong>Empfohlen:<\/strong>\r<br><ul class=\""bb_ul\""><li><strong>Betriebssystem:<\/strong> 64-bit Betriebssystem (Windows 7, Windows 8 &amp; Windows 8.1)\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Prozessor:<\/strong> Intel Core i3-4170 or AMD FX-8300 oder h\u00f6her\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Arbeitsspeicher:<\/strong> 8 GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Grafik:<\/strong> DX11 Kompatible GeForce 760 or AMD HD 8800 oder h\u00f6her mit 4GB RAM\r<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Version 11\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Netzwerk:<\/strong> Breitband-Internetverbindung\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Speicherplatz:<\/strong> 15 GB verf\u00fcgbarer Speicherplatz\r<br><\/li><li><strong>Soundkarte:<\/strong> DX11 kompatibel\r<\/li><\/ul>""},""mac_requirements"":[],""linux_requirements"":[],""legal_notice"":""Dead by Daylight ist eine Handelsmarke von Behaviour Interactive Inc. Alle anderen Handelsmarken sind Eigentum ihrer jeweiligen Inhaber. Entwickelt von Behaviour Digital und publiziert von Starbreeze Studios. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.""}}}"
    'Pass the string to my parsing function (note this is parsing, below is called deserialization) 
    a = editJson(a)
    'Create an object using Newtonsoft's Json, set Example (class) varaibles using the Json data (a)
    Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Example)(a)
    'Show a message box with one of the object's names from the JSon class.
    MsgBox(obj.id.data.name)
```

Here we need to parse out the number *381210* and replace it with our *id* property name

```
Function editJson(ByVal str As String) As String
    'Get the first occurance of "
    Dim first As Integer = str.IndexOf("""")
    'Get the next occurance of " (3 is the starting offset)
    Dim last As Integer = str.IndexOf("""", 3)
    'Remove everything inside the first set of quotes
    str = str.Remove(first + 1, last - 2)
    'Insert ID where your number used to be (we need to do this because our JSon converter is looking for the 381210 as a proprety, but we can't easily assign a dynamic property, so instead we parse out the property name and replace it with our ID [note this id is also duplicated data as it shows up as the steam_appid]
    Return str.Insert(2, "id")
End Function
```

Finally, we need to have our class structure match the JSON we are recieving, which can be done like this:

```
Public Class PcRequirements
    Public Property minimum As String
    Public Property recommended As String
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property steam_appid As Integer
    Public Property required_age As Integer
    Public Property is_free As Boolean
    Public Property dlc As Integer()
    Public Property detailed_description As String
    Public Property about_the_game As String
    Public Property short_description As String
    Public Property supported_languages As String
    Public Property header_image As String
    Public Property website As String
    Public Property pc_requirements As PcRequirements
    Public Property mac_requirements As Object()
    Public Property linux_requirements As Object()
    Public Property legal_notice As String
End Class

Public Class Game
    Public Property success As Boolean
    Public Property data As Data
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property id As Game
End Class
```

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes) post for an explanation to why the class structure must match. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252462/need-a-class-structure-to-serialize-json-in-vb-net) post for more information on the making the class structure.

It is worth noting the difference between parsing and deserialization in these terms parsing would be more along the lines of writing a loop to go through and read the data, splitting it into an array at each new property type; deserialization on the other hand we are putting it directly into an object (class structure) which is a much more specific term (which is why there was some confusion in the comments) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305368/deserialization-vs-parsing) gives a brief explanation of the difference

Comment: This might have been useful to someone who has an idea about JSON but surely the OP needs to know the classes to use.  Even using a robot it will need a fixup because `381210` will be an illegal class/property name.  Besides, in spite of the title, the question asks how `to parse the following input and get only "Dead by Daylight"`.  Linking to another answer and pasting it isnt very helpful *as* an answer

Comment: In this situation should one answer for the question in the body or in the title? I suspect the OP does not know the difference between deserialization and parsing in this instance.

Comment: Its six to five and pick em IMO.  I might have shown how to parse just because his/her previous post (now deleted) also made clear they just wanted one piece of info.  The "hard" part for someone new to JSON is making the classes and this doesnt help with that.  (after a while you can tell when a paste-this-code answer is expected)